# Jagged text issue while using rotation webkit

Tags: css

Any ideas on how to make the text appear 'inline'?

I made a polaroid photo effect on my portfolio, the rotate completely ruins the font, unsure if there is a fix.

[image]

rest assured, it's not so bad with my current font but other fonts look awful.

Code:

```
figure.polaroid {
width: 221px;
height: 240px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
background-color: white;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px black;
margin-top: 25px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Show us your css, tell us what browser gives problems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me guess, Chrome?

Try `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

I've read that some people avoid this issue by applying a 3d transform for rotation, such as `transform: rotate3d(1, 2.0, 3.0, 10deg)`, so that might be a cleaner solution.

Comment: With `rotate(3deg)` I was seeing rendering problems around the edges of the nine pieces which made up a `border-image` block. Using your suggestion to change to `rotate3d(1, 2.0, 3.0, 3deg)` removed the glitches completely.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to apply `text-shadow` to make font smooth.

Here you can try different shadows, pick a subtle one and check how it looks with your rotation:
http://www.elfboy.com/text-shadow/